# Qt5 QML: swap two Items in ListView

Tags: qt, qml, model-view

i'm using model view in qml.

```
    ListView{
        id: targetParameter
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 20
        spacing: 10
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        interactive: false
        model: proxyModelCharacterization
        delegate: ParameterChangeTarget {
            paramWidht: {
                if(name === "NAME"){
                    targetParameter.width * 0.11
                }else{
                    targetParameter.width * 0.42
                }
            }
            paramHeight: targetParameter.height * 0.95
        }
    }
```

with this list view, I have three elements (for example Rectangle).
rect1, rect2, rect3.
i want to swap rect2 and rect3, but i can't change the order in which they are instantiated on my controller.

how can i swap two element on list view?
every kind of help or suggestion are greatly appreciated.

Comment: QML Dynamic View Ordering Tutorial 3 - Moving Dragged Items: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-tutorials-dynamicview-dynamicview3-example.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.move()` method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#move-method) to move an element in a `ListModel`.

In the following example, the elements are added in the `ListModel` once, in the `Component.onCompleted` signal. You can then move them up or down (in the model and hence, the view) by clicking on the corresponding buttons. The buttons use the `move()` method of `ListModel`.

Example:

```
ListModel {
    id: listModel
}

ListView {
    id: listView

    anchors.fill: parent

    spacing: 10
    model: listModel
    delegate: Rectangle {
        height: btnMoveUp.height
        width: listView.width
        color: "red"

        Button {
            id: btnMoveUp

            anchors.left: parent.left
            text: "Move Up"
            enabled: index !== 0

            onClicked: listModel.move(index, index-1,1)
        }

        Button {
            id: btnMoveDown

            anchors.left: btnMoveUp.right
            text: "Move Down"
            enabled: index !== listModel.count - 1

            onClicked: listModel.move(index, index+1,1)
        }

        Text {
            anchors {
                left: btnMoveDown.right
                right: parent.right
                verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }
            text: model.name
        }
    }
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    listModel.append({name: "Item 1"});
    listModel.append({name: "Item 2"});
    listModel.append({name: "Item 3"});
    listModel.append({name: "Item 4"});
    listModel.append({name: "Item 5"});
}
```